# Why are my decimal places not counting correctly?

Tags: python

I am trying to print pi with a specific number of decimal places based on an input. When I enter 99 decimal places, it prints out 99. When I enter 100 decimal places, it only prints out 99. When I enter 101 decimal places it prints out 101. I want to be able to limit it to 100 decimal places. I am new to python and trying to work an exercise. Here is my code:

```
from mpmath import mp

def pi_decimals():
    while True:
        spaces = int(input('How many decimal places do you wish to use? '))
        
        if spaces not in range(0,102):
            print('Enter a number between 0 and 100!')
            continue
        else:
            mp.dps = int(spaces) + 1
                        
        print(mp.pi)
        break

pi_decimals()
```

Comment: What is `mp` here?

Comment: @Grismar `from mpmath import mp`

Comment: The issue is that a value ending in a `0` at the end of the decimals won't print that `0`.  Compare `mp.dps` values `32`, `33` and `34` (where a `0` occurs naturally in pi). At the position where you're looking at, the value would end in a `9`, but since the next digit is `>= 5`, it rounds to a `0` and doesn't print. Are you looking to print it anyway, or does this answer your question already?

Comment: I originally had the code as importing all, but then came across something else that had import mp. I seem to remember from a class that it is not always advised to import all and should only import a specific module. Very new to this.

Comment: Grismar - that makes sense. I wasn't aware of that. So, anytime the decimal ends with a 0, either naturally or via rounding, it won't print?

Comment: It won't, but if you need it to anyway, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a value ending in a `0` at the end of the decimals won't print that `0`.  Compare `mp.dps` values `32`, `33` and `34` (where a `0` occurs naturally in pi). At the position where you're looking at, the value would end in a `9`, but since the next digit is `>= 5`, it rounds to a `0` and doesn't print.

However, see this:

```
from mpmath import mp

for dps in [32, 33, 34, 100, 101, 102]:
    mp.dps = dps
    s = str(mp.pi)
    print(s, len(s))

for dps in [32, 33, 34, 100, 101, 102]:
    s = mp.nstr(mp.pi, dps, strip_zeros=False)
    print(s, len(s))
```

Result:

```
3.1415926535897932384626433832795 33
3.1415926535897932384626433832795 33
3.141592653589793238462643383279503 35
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068 101
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068 101
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798 103
3.1415926535897932384626433832795 33
3.14159265358979323846264338327950 34
3.141592653589793238462643383279503 35
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068 101
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170680 102
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798 103
```

So, I think you're looking for `mp.nstr(mp.pi, dps, strip_zeros=False)` to get the result you want printed.

Comment: Ok. I see. That is fairly advanced (for me) but I see what is happening here. That is very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Basically, to keep it simple, it means replacing `print(mp.pi)` in your code with `print(mp.nstr(mp.pi, int(spaces) + 1, strip_zeros=False)` - hope that helps. If you feel this answers your question, please click the checkmark next to the answer, so the question is no longer marked as unanswered. If you need more of an answer, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks again.